# More than 3 DNS server in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dns, glibc, resolver, resolv

I need to configure more than 3 DNS servers in "/etc/resolv.conf".
According to man, it is not supported so I have to recompile glibc

> Up to MAXNS (currently 3) name servers may be listed, one per line. If there are multiple servers,
> the resolver library queries them in the order listed. If no nameserver entries are present, the
> default is to use the name server on the local machine. (The algorithm used is to try a name server,
> and if the query times out, try the next, until out of name servers, then repeat trying all name
> servers until a maximum number of retries are performed.)

I changed the constant `MAXNS` in `resolv/bits/types/res_state.h` and I compiled as follows:

```
mkdir glibc-build
cd glibc-build
../glibc-(version of glibc)/configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/glibc-testing --with-tls --enable-add-ons=nptl
make
make install
```

I tried to ping some sites and with the help of Wireshark I tried to see which servers it was addressing. The servers still addressed the first three addresses.

I also saw that the file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/res_state.h` did not change.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`--prefix=/usr/local/lib/glibc-testing` builds glibc for installation into that directory hierarchy, so it will be isolated from the rest of the system. This is a good thing because the `MAXNS` change is a pretty drastic ABI break, so it would require rebuilding quite a few programs. `make install` typically crashes half-way through with `--prefix=/usr`, leaving a system behind that is no longer usable. Upstream glibc also does not have support for Debian-syle multi-arch directories (`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` in addition to `/usr/include`).

Anyway, to increase the number of supported name servers in a way that would be suitable for inclusion into upstream glibc, the following steps are needed:

- Stop using the per-name server file descriptors in `struct __res_state` (the `nssocks` array) in `resolv/res_send.c`. The stub resolver keeps only one socket open, so it does not make sense to use an array anyway.
- Enhance the internal `struct resolv_conf` to keep track of name servers, in addition to the search list entries.
- Update the backwards-compatibility matching code to check for name server changes in `_res` (applications may directly write to `_res`, in which case these name servers should be used). This parallels the search list code.
- Adjust the actual DNS client code in `resolv/res_send.c` to use all name servers (not just those in `struct __res_state`).

This is a non-trivial contribution, so it would need [FSF copyright assignment](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Contribution%20checklist#FSF_copyright_assignment).